# how to auto position infobox google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have a lot of markers on my page, when a mouse hovers on that, an infobox appears

but it overlaps all the others markers, i want to auto position it somehow so that it doesnt hide the other markers...

```
var infoboxOptions = {
         content: ''
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 140
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-1, -50)
        ,zIndex: 1000
        ,closeBoxMargin: "1px 1px 1px 1px"            
    ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1,1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: true
    };
```

is there any way i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

How will you check whether there are markers or not within a particular span (depending on your infobox dimensions)....

You have provided **pane** as **floatPane** which has highest z-index...[check this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes)

Provide some other pane and see....

If there is still no success..
I think the better way is to give the opacity to your infobox so that markers behind your infobox can be seen ..

good luck..